# how to get ADF pipeline historical data

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory

I want to retrieve adf pipeline data log of the month of January. But filtering is only available up to 45 days. I am not able get data before 45 days. How to get data log from January?

In the image you can see jan 1st to jan 31st is trying to be filtered but no data found

[image]

I've heard about data monitoring, azure data factory analytics. Will these help for getting historical log or does they start collecting from future only? If any of these works explain how to do the full process please.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Keeping Azure Data Factory metrics and pipeline-run data
Data Factory stores pipeline-run data for only 45 days. Use Azure Monitor if you want to keep that data for a longer time

for diagnostic settings :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-configure-diagnostics

[image]